# Using few columns from associated table with a SQL Join

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, oop

Whenever I want to avoid NxN queries, I use `includes` in Rails. But sometimes the included table might have large number of fields.

So to avoid performance issues what I do is, I do a join and I select only required fields from the associated table.

But this does not feel right at all. I feels like violating something although Im not sure what.

I understand that when we do `includes`, we cannot specify the `select` clause. How do we achieve this without doing a join and polluting(?) the objects.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "nice" rails way to do this. 
Like you said it isn't possible and also not usefull to combine `includes` and `select` because `ActiveRecord::Base` wraps every query to an object. This whould mean that loading only `id` and `name` and leaving out `description` and `user_id` for example whould bring you in a situation where you might lose the content of  `description` and `user_id` when saving the incomplete object to the database.

So you can only do this using plain sql and leave out the object mapping of `ActiveRecord` so you don't get in danger of losing data. You can also do thisthrough the database connection established by `ActiveRecord` like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT id,name FROM table_name WHERE <conditions>").each do |row|
  row["id"]  #access id of each result
end
```

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection` contains a handle for the connection established by using the environment access data provided in your `config/database.yml` so you can use the same database connection model independent.

Comment: Thanks. What about the `eager_load` solution? It seems rather pretty right?

Comment: Yes its definiifly the cleaner solution of this problem but you may come to a point where speed gains a higher priority then nice ruby code.